# CountDownTimer seconds in XX format

Tags: android, time, countdown, seconds

I have a CountDownTimer like that:

```
                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {                      
                             tv1.setText(""+String.format("%d:%d", 
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));  
                     }`
```

But at seconds less than 10 the textview should display the second letter with a zero. So that it will look like "1:02" and not like "1:2".

Comment: So what are you saying... `if it's less than 10, then add a '0'`?

Comment: yeah i`ve tried it but it didnt work; maybe you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially from the Android Formatter [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html), "pad the number with leading zeros", which requires you to specify width:

In the format string, your target width is 2. To pad with 0's you prepend a 0 to that for your decimal numbers (d), yielding:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d", decimal1, decimal2) ...
```

Comment: StackOverflow, etc. really helped me by making the Android docs approachable / linking into them often. There are a lot of good answers here. Good luck with your project.